# Cannot load google map javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

The follow tells me that GMap2 is not defined. But the code that uses GMap2 is in the callback.

```
        $(function() {
        $('#sample').click(function() {
            $.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;key=API_KEY_HERE", function() {
                var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapTest"));
                map.setCenter(new GLatLng(18, -77.4), 13);
                map.setUIToDefault();

            });
        });
    });

<a id="sample">Click Me</a>
<div id="mapTest" style="width: 200px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, the OP has supplied an API key. I have removed it from the question and replaced it with API_KEY_HERE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go two ways with this:

**1. Continue to use `$.getScript`**:

It seems that you need both an `async=2` parameter as well as a different callback structure for it to work. My answer is adapted to your code from this [great walkthrough here](http://thinkdrastic.tumblr.com/post/88217865/jquery-getscript-and-the-google-maps-api).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function map_callback(){
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapTest"));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(18, -77.4), 13);
        map.setUIToDefault();
    }

    $(function(){
       $('#sample').click(function(){
          $.getScript("http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=true&amp;callback=map_callback&amp;async=2&amp;key=API_KEY_HERE");
       }
    }
</script>
```

**2. Use the Google AJAX Loader**

Since you are already using a Google Library, why not [use their loader](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/documentation/) to help you out:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABCDEFG"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

   google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
       $('#sample').click(function(){
          google.load("maps", "2", {"callback" : function(){
            var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("mapTest"));
            map.setCenter(new GLatLng(18, -77.4), 13);
            map.setUIToDefault();
          } });
       });
   }, true); // Passing true, though undocumented, is supposed to work like jQuery DOM ready
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried both and decided to stick with the jquery because the google ajax loader is an extra 16kb.

Comment: @Shawn glad it worked for you! Just so you know, it is 16kb uncompressed, but it is sent compressed from the Google servers, so it is only 5.8k

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the if the browser is compatible?   I do this in all my GMAP applications, although it rarely fails...

```
if (GBrowserIsCompatible())
```

Comment: It does not find the script any at all. It also tells me that function is not available.

Comment: Based on both functions giving errors, it sounded like a script not being load error, but it looks like Doug helped you out.    Good luck with your application...